# custom directive to change input type number format when no decimal

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to change the ngModel (input type="number") Format. `When there is no decimal the Output must be: 25,00`. This code work good in angularjs 1.2.23 version as you see, but in 1.6.4 version not work. any other solution?

```js
var app= angular.module('myApp',[]);
app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.test=25;
})

.directive('price', function($filter) {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       require: '?ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
           ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                return $filter('number')(value,2);
           });
       }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="number" ng-model="test" step=".01" price>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from AngularJS 1.3 ([db044c40](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/db044c408a7f8082758b96ab739348810c36e15a)), the type `input[number]` throws a validation error when the input is not a number, which is your case since the number filter returns a string.

If you convert it to a number by using `Number(...)` or `parseFloat` you will fall into a Javascript limitation for floating point numbers where the rightmost zeroes are removed and the input will show the value `25`  instead of `25.00`.

Since this validation [is also in the `$formatters` array](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/4c5afb5cc2f72e966be9ee4f80732dd6e143d91d/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1517) a simple workaround is to use `unshift` instead of `push` when adding your custom formatter, which will allow it to run **after** the validation:

```
.directive('price', function($filter) {
    return {
       restrict: 'A',
       require: '?ngModel',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
           ngModel.$formatters.unshift(function (value) {
                return $filter('number')(value,2);
           });
       }
    }
})
```

Of course, if your formatter needs to do some additional work you can always `push` one to handle invalid inputs and `unshift` another that adds the decimal places by calling `.toFixed(2)`.